# Extrapolate an Interpolation scale

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, interpolation-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are real Banach spaces with a continuous embedding $X\subset Y$. For given $0<\theta<1$ I am interested in constructing using the norms of $X$ and $Y$ a  (Quasi-) Banach space $Z\subset X$ (as large as possible), such that interpolation with the K-method yields $(Z,Y)_{\theta,q}=X$ for some $1\leq q\leq \infty.$

I tried searching for "extrapolation of Banach spaces". But the references I found are concerning other questions.

Comment: The term "extrapolation" is used in the way which is close to what you are interested in on page 1143 of the survey: Kalton, Montgomery-Smith,  Interpolation of Banach spaces. Handbook of the geometry of Banach spaces, Vol. 2, 1131-1175, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2003.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reference. I had a look. On first glance it seems, that it does not help me a lot. There the question is weather a property of a member (or a subset) of an interpolation scale implies the property for all spaces of the scale. My question could be phrased like. Suppose you have a scale $(X_\theta)_{\theta\in[0,1]}$ and you forgot about all spaces but $(X_\theta)_{\theta\in[0.5,1]}$. Can you reconstruct the missing spaces?

Comment: Kalton (1946-2010) once told me that the problem of extension of interpolation scales is a difficult one. Unfortunately I do not have any references on this. I would like to mention that results which you find in the reference I provided can show you that some scales are not extendable (at least in the Banach range).For example, it cannot happen that $X_\frac12$ is nonreflexive while $X_\frac13$ is reflexive. For complex interpolation you can try analytic extension.